# I wonder why this js code is not working?

Tags: javascript

I believe  js shoulod support:

```
<script>
text = "This Title";
document.write( text.heading(1));
</script>
```

but it is not so. Any correction or explanatioin?

Comment: There really isn't enough info here, but if this is all the code, `heading` is not a method of `String` in javascript. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This question/code makes absolutely no sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: SAMS TEACH YOURSELF JS a famous book contains this code, I was tempted to use it somewhere.

Comment: Does that book define their own `heading` method somewhere? Are you sure that's the exact code from the book? Is that the famous *...in 24 hours* book or the famous *...in 21 days* book?

Comment: Try to avoid document.write() as it lakes explicity abaout the final outcome / structure of your document.

Comment: According to Google books, [the `heading` function is added to the String prototype before this code is used.](http://books.google.com/books?id=bKxhgNopylMC&lpg=PA95&ots=tbpMUHY1KX&dq=sams%20teach%20yourself%20javascript%20heading&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q=sams%20teach%20yourself%20javascript%20heading&f=false)

Comment: True as @Mathletics suggests. The book OP is referring to is available [here](http://www.onlinetechbooks.com/javascript-books/SAMS%20Teach%20Yourself%20JavaScript%20in%2024%20Hours%204th%20(2007).pdf) & the relevant code is on page 94-95. The script will only work if you include the code in Listing 6.4 in the book (p.95) prior to the code you wrote here.

Comment: I have got the right answers. My doubts are cleared. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to write `<h1>This Title</h1>` but there is no heading method in String prototype.

HTML Tag Methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff806183%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) may be a bit confusing cause javascript supports just few of html tags.

If you really need to make `String.heading` work, try this:

```
String.prototype.heading = function(level) {
  return '<h' + level + '>' + this + '</h' + level + '>';
};
```

Note: extending prototype of built in objects is generally bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you do `.heading(1) ??`

```
<script>
text = "This Title";
document.write(text);
</script>
```

Or you are trying to change title?

`document.title = text;`

Or you want to add text to particular place on the webpage?

```
<div id="heading1">
</div>
<div id="heading2">
</div>

<script>
text = "This Title";
text2 = "This is not Title";
document.getElementById('heading1').innerHTML  = text;
document.getElementById('heading2').innerHTML  = text2;
</script>
```

Comment: .heading(1) is just suggestive to .heading(2) or .heading(3) etc.

Comment: .heading(2) makes no more sense than .heading(1). You could only do this if text were an object and heading an object method which accepts a number as parameter, which it is not (text is a string).

Comment: The sufficient detailed code is :fucnction addhead (level) {
..........
.........
.........
}

String.prototype.heading = addhead;
document.write( "This is a test".heading(1));

Comment: @HarjitSingh You really should include all of that in your question.

Comment: Oh! sorry, I mistook as something in built. So I did not customize. Thanks Tyblitz your comment has made me aware of the reality.

Comment: @Tyblitz A String in JavaScript *is* a type of object, and Strings [do have methods on them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_unrelated_to_HTML). Obviously, however, `heading` is not a built-in method defined on String.